# Drilldown is not visible in Siebel local environment

Tags: siebel, drilldown

I have made database extract from server, created mobile web client user etc. to set up my local environment. In my local environment I can't see some drilldowns that are visible in the server. I checked responsibilities, views - everything is in place. I copied server srf file to my local env, and still no luck. Can you please suggest me what am I missing? Probably some additional configuration needs to be done. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the drilldown is visible on the server, it is properly configured. You could try testing on a dedicated client to ensure this (local SRF + server DB) .

Check if the target view is in YOUR responsibility.

Check if the source applet has any dynamic toggle so it toggled into a different applet.

Also check if you have setup the right ApplicationName under [Siebel] section of your local cfg file.

Comment: I tested with local srf + serverDb and drilldown is wokring ok. It means that my localdb is not working properly? View is in my resp,  application name is ok.

Comment: Ok, so issue is in your localdb. Is the local access flag of that view [checked](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B40099_02/books/Secur/Secur_AccessControl25.html).  Are you able to navigate to the target view in your local manually (via sitemap) ? You could test this by changing the url to SWECmd=GotoView&SWEView=<TARGET VIEW NAME>

Comment: as it turned out, in one of my responsibility local access flag was not checked. Thank you.